# Raphael.JS, prevent event bubbling

Tags: javascript, raphael

In the following fiddle, how can I prevent the click event from bubbling up and calling "AddVertex" when I am dragging and dropping?

To replicate:

1. Click on document (will add a vertex)
2. Click on vertex and drag, upon releasing the mouse addVertex is called which creates another vertex.

I have tried all sorts of combinations of event.stopPropogation, return false etc. in the up function to no joy.

http://jsfiddle.net/paulsidebottom/YzN8K/

Comment: The event that moves (drag) the vertex is not the same event that creates the new vertex (click), so `stopPropagation` isn't going to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to make it work by changing it to this:

```
function addVertex(e)
{
    if(e.target.nodeName !== 'circle'){
        paper.vertex(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    }
    console.log("Added vertex.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting a JSfiddle it made it easier to figure out the correct answer.

Comment: Posting a JsFiddle will always help you get a better answer.